# how can I read input from terminal in a C program

Tags: c, terminal

I have a circuit connected to a thermistor and using system(command) I can get it to read the value into the terminal but I can't get it to send the value properly to my C program.

I'm sending code to the terminal to run, and this code is returning a value in the terminal. I want to take this value into my C program

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>       //for Log

float Vo;                     //voltage out
float Ro = 5000;        //value of resistance at 25C in the thermistor
float R ;               //value of fixed resistor
float B = 3977;         //Beta constant
float T0 = 298.15;      //25 degrees C in Kelvin
//float logR2,  R2,T;
//float A = 1.281426510e-03, B = 2.368116050e-04, C = 0.9002008458e-07;  // Ste$


    int main(){
    
    char command[50];
    
    //get the Analog value
    sprintf(command, "cd /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio\\:device0 && cat in_voltage0_raw"$
    Vo = system(command);
    printf("Analog Reading: %d\n", Vo);
return 0;
}
```

An example output would be

> 3973
>
> Analog Reading: 4319452

where is the 4319452 coming from? I want it to read 3973

After reading the comments I tried to use fopen
in the following way

```
//#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>       //for Log

float Vo;                       //voltage out
float Ro = 5000;        //value of resistance at 25C in the thermistor
float R ;               //value of fixed resistor
float B = 3977;         //Beta constant
float T0 = 298.15;      //25 degrees C in Kelvin
//float logR2,  R2,T;
//float A = 1.281426510e-03, B = 2.368116050e-04, C = 0.9002008458e-07;  // Steinhart-Hart and Hart Coefficients



int main(){

FILE *fp;
char command[50];
int c;
//get the Analog value
//sprintf(command, "cd /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio\\:device0 && cat in_voltage0_raw" );
fp = fopen("/sys/bus/iio/devices/iio\\:device0/in_voltage0_raw","r");
while(1) {
      c = fgetc(fp);
      if( feof(fp) ) {
         break ;
      }
      printf("%c", c);
   }
   fclose(fp);
//Vo[i] = system(command);

printf("Analog Reading: %d\n", c);

return 0;
}
```

I get

> Segmentation fault

after running the code

I edited the code in the following way

```
sprintf(command, "cd /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0 && cat in_voltage0_raw"$
```

After I run it I get the following output

> 3 9 6 8
>
> Analog Reading: ▒

It reads the output correctly once but in the second

```
printf("Analog Reading: %d\n", c);
```

it gives me

> Analog Reading: ▒

Full code up to this point

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>       //for Log

int Vo;                 //voltage out
float Ro = 5000;        //value of resistance at 25C in the thermistor
float R ;               //value of fixed resistor
float B = 3977;         //Beta constant
float T0 = 298.15;      //25 degrees C in Kelvin
//float logR2,  R2,T;
//float A = 1.281426510e-03, B = 2.368116050e-04, C = 0.9002008458e-07;  // Steinhart-Hart and Hart Coefficients



int main(){

FILE *fp;
char command[50];
int c;
//get the Analog value
//sprintf(command, "cd /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio\\:device0 && cat in_voltage0_raw" );
fp = fopen("/sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/in_voltage0_raw","r");
if ( fp == NULL ){
perror("Error: ");
return(-1);
}
while(1) {
      c = fgetc(fp);
      if( feof(fp) ) {
         break ;
      }
      printf("%c ", c);
//      Vo = c;
   }

   fclose(fp);
//Vo[i] = system(command);

printf("Analog Reading: %c\n", c);

return 0;

}
```

I solved the problem by taking every character read and putting it in an array

Here the working code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>       //for Log

char Vo[10];                    //voltage out
float Ro = 5000;        //value of resistance at 25C in the thermistor
float R ;               //value of fixed resistor
float B = 3977;         //Beta constant
float T0 = 298.15;      //25 degrees C in Kelvin
//float logR2,  R2,T;
//float A = 1.281426510e-03, B = 2.368116050e-04, C = 0.9002008458e-07;  // Steinhart-Hart and Hart Coefficients



int main(){

FILE *fp;
char command[50];
int c;
//get the Analog value
//sprintf(command, "cd /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio\\:device0 && cat in_voltage0_raw" );
fp = fopen("/sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/in_voltage0_raw","r");
if ( fp == NULL ){
perror("Error: ");
return(-1);
}
int i=0;
while(1) {
      c = fgetc(fp);
      if( feof(fp) ) {
         break ;
      }
      printf("%c ", c);
if (c != '\0'){
  Vo[i] = c;
++i;
}
//      Vo = c;
   }

   fclose(fp);
//Vo[i] = system(command);

printf("Analog Reading: %s\n", Vo);

return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 3 9 7 0
>
> Analog Reading: 3970

Comment: Take a look at `popen` and examples of the usage.

Comment: Alternatively (and looks like it is way simpler and straightforward) simply `fopen` the `in_voltage0_raw` file in your program and read as regular file.

Comment: @EugeneSh. in_voltage0_raw is not a file. It is a command I'm sending to the circuit I'm using (beaglebone black) to read the analog input. It spits the output in the terminal and I'm trying to take that output to my C program

Comment: `cat in_voltage0_raw` is definitely treating it as file.

Comment: Yes, you should absolutely be able to read from /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/in_voltage0_raw as a file, depending on permissions.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I tried to open the file with fopen with no luck take a look at my edited code

Comment: Check if `fp` is `NULL` and if it is, use `perror` to tell why

Comment: @EugeneSh. it says no such file or directory. I think because, I'm running my code from /Documents and the file is in /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio\\:device0/in_voltage0_raw. How can I get around this?

Comment: maybe something with the excess of the backslashes. What is the actual path (as you see it in the shell)?

Comment: @EugeneSh. the actual path is /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio\:device0/in_voltage0_raw

Comment: I think you need to use just `/sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/in_voltage0_raw`. The backslash is for the shell.

Comment: @EugeneSh. the path works fine now, thanks but I have another problem. See the edit

Comment: It prints the `c` read after EOF. Strange it is not printing integer value though. Are you sure it is the exact code?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I added the full code up to this point

Comment: So the value of `c` is likely `-1`, because it is read at EOF. You should check it instead of `feof`. See [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thank you for the help. I think I know where to go from here. If you want to post a answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're assuming the output from the system function is your value; it is not.  The return value from `system()` is the exit status of the shell and it is an `int` and not a float.

I'm not sure what that return code is but you are not casting correctly and I'm surprised you're not getting a compile Warning like:

```
t.c:22:36: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'float' [-Wformat]
    printf("Analog Reading: %d\n", Vo);
                            ~~     ^~
                            %f
1 warning generated.
```

Basically this means that you are taking an `int` and putting it not a `float` without a proper cast or conversion.  Its not actually the data you want.  You want the content of the file.

What you might want to do is to read `/sys/bus/iio/devices/iio\\:device0/in_voltage0_raw` directly as a string and then convert it to the appropriate numeric value.

Technically what you're trying to do is read the stdout from the shell through a return value which is not possible with the function you are using.

Comment: Could you show me how I can do that? I have not done this before

Comment: I suggest that you clarify what problem you have.  It's not intended to be an interactive debugging forum.   You can find examples of using fread here https://www.educative.io/edpresso/c-reading-data-from-a-file-using-fread and if you have other questions feel free to post a new question.

Comment: While I appreciate you trying to help me. Your comment is unnecessary, I posted the question to the best of my knowledge and people were able to understand what I was trying to do